# Data does not show up in table view cell when i run my code

Tags: ios, swift, api, uitableview

Please help! I've tried everything. If anyone has any advice on how i can display my data in the table view cell, I would be eternally grateful. I'm new to iOS and am learning on a very steep pace. I grabbed data from an API that returned data in the form of JSON, parsed it, created my table view with its table view cells, but i can't seem to figure out how to print the data i parsed through in the table view cell.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView! {
    didSet {
        myTableView.dataSource = self
        myTableView.delegate = self
    }
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let url = NSURL(string: "https://api.viacom.com/apiKey=someKey")!
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)

    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { data, response, error in
        if let response = response, data = data {

            var json: [String: AnyObject]!
            do {
                json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions()) as! [String : AnyObject]
                } catch {
                        print(error)

                }

    //2 - Store in model, forloop through them, store into temparray,add to main array?


             let episodes = json["response"] as! [String: AnyObject]
             let meta = episodes["episodes"] as! [AnyObject]
             let description = meta[2]["description"]! as! String?
             //let title = meta[2]["title"] as! String?
             let episodeNumber = meta[2]["episodeNumber"]! as! String?

             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                 self.myTableView.reloadData()})

            data = [episodeNumber!, description!]


            print("Episode Number: \(episodeNumber!)\n" + "Description: \(description!)")

            } else {

            print(error)

            }
        }

    task.resume()
}

let data = [description]

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel!.text = "\(self.data)"

    return cell
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
{

    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

Comment: @vikingosegundo oops, that's a comment i forgot to edit out. I just updated it.

Comment: @vikingosegundo yes, i just one cell to display the information that comes out in my output which is Episode Number and Description of a series that i obtained form an API. My cell only displays '[(Function)]' at the moment while my output box has the correct data i requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the failure is too much of data manipulation. There is no need to use so many variables and pass around data unnecessarily. You are getting correct output in console when printing it because you used variables "episodeNumber" and "description".

```
print("Episode Number: \(episodeNumber!)\n" + "Description: \(description!)")
```

And getting wrong data in variable "data".

So better thing would be that you should use episodeNumber and description variables to print data in Cell.

```
cell.textLabel!.text = "Episode Number: \(self.episodeNumber)\n" + "Description: \(description)"
```

But for this you have to make variable `episodeNumber` a global variable.

So declare it outside the function.

```
var episodeNumber = String()
```

and remove the `let` keyword from line

```
let episodeNumber = meta[2]["episodeNumber"]! as! String?
```

You have to add some `self.` keywords which the compiler will suggest you so you don't have to worry about that, just keep on double clicking the suggestions.

Now, your code looks fine to run and get desired output.

Comment: It finally works. You are a lifesaver. Can't thank you enough..A thousand thank you's!!!! @JayMehta

Answer (score 1):

Your codes look very messy to me. However, I'm just assuming that you have successfully fetched the JSON data. Fetching data is asynchronous. You therefore need to add a dispatch code inside.
After your this line of code:

`let episodeNumber = meta[2]["episodeNumber"]! as! String?`

Add this

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
       self.tableView.reloadData()})
```

EDIT:

```
@IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView! {
    didSet {
        myTableView.dataSource = self
        myTableView.delegate = self // Add This
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes! I fetched my data. I do agree my code is messy. I'm just trying to make it work. Thanks so much for answering! I get an error saying: ambiguous reference to member 'tableView'

Comment: edited my answer, it's not a good practice to drag and drop a table inside a view controller. However assuming you had to do so, you need to add a delegate of your table.

Comment: Really appreciate your help with this, @jo3birdtalk! I edited in the fixes to my code and now myTableView cell displays: '[(Function)]' ...however I still have the issuewhere i receive data in my output that proves the parsed information is correct, but i can't seem to find a way to display it in my table view cell. ]: do you have any advice for this?

Comment: Does the printing of message works? `print("Episode Number: \(episodeNumber!)\n" + "Description: \(description!)")`

Comment: What is `self.data`? From your codes, you only need 1 row, and that row will contain `self.data` in your text label.

Comment: self.data is my attempt at trying to fetch the array: data = [episodeNumber!, description!] because i don't know how to access episodeNumber or description so that my table view cell recognizes it. :\ So the printing of the message only works in my output box, but not in myTableView cell @jo3birdtalk

Comment: @jo3birdtalk, could you elaborate *it's not a good practice to drag and drop a table inside a view controller.*?

Comment: @VanessaRodriguez if your `self.data` is an array, you need to use `indexPath.row` to specify the index of your array, so it can display information. Example: `self.data[indexPath.row]`

Comment: @vikingosegundo it seems from her entire class, it is only performing table related work, and thus it would be better to use it would be better to use UITableViewController rather than UIViewController, and bringing in a UITableView into it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, Jo3birdtalk and @vikingosegundo , it really helped me out and taught me several things I was doing wrong!!  Jay Mehta's answer was the last piece of the puzzle. You guys rock!

Answer (score 0):

```
let data = [description]
```

is a short form of

```
let data = [self.description]
```

and `self.description()` is the viewController's description method used for printing debug description. That is why

```
cell.textLabel!.text = "\(self.data)"
```

gives you `[(Function)]`, as you just created an array with a stored function in it.